# Using Ajax in MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to inject a view using Ajax but it's not quite working. I know nothing about Ajax but I'm trying to learn. What am I missing here or am I completely wrong the way I'm doing this.

```
    foreach(ect...) {
   <tr>
       <td>
      <a href="#" onclick="AjaxStoryClick(@item.Id)" style="color:dodgerblue; font-weight: bold">@item.Name</a>

       <script type="text/javascript">
function AjaxStoryClick(storyid) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UserStoriesList", "Estimate")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: storyid,
        success: function(result){
            $('#stories').html(result);

        }
     });         
}    

      </script>
```

Controller:

```
       public ActionResult UserStoriesList(int id)
    {
        ActiveEpicId = id;
        var userstories = userRepository.Select().Where(x => x.EpicId.Equals(id)).ToList();
        return PartialView("UserStoriesList",userstories);
    }
```

Comment: are you getting any errors ? Did you use breakpoints to see whether you are getting  a call to your Action Method ?

Comment: na I'm not even getting to the action method.

Comment: try changing `data:storyid` to `data:'{id:'+storyid+'}'`, otherwise what you're actually sending it `Request["1"]`, `Request["2"]` instead of `Request["id"]` (which is what the MVC engine is looking for to populate `int id` in your action)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `UserStoriesList` Action method of Type `HttpPost` ? Your Ajax request is of type `POST`. So it will be only handled by HttpPost type UserStoriesList action method.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UserStoriesList(int id)
 {
   // your code goes here
 }
```

If your ActionMethod is not of Type `HttpPost` (that means it is of `HttpGet` type) , you can use a jquery get ajax call to get the data

Make sure your parameter name in your ajax call is same as of the parameter name in your action method.

```
function AjaxStoryClick(storyid) {
  $.get('@Url.Action("UserStoriesList", "Estimate")',{id : storyid},function(result){
     $('#stories').html(result);
  });
}
```

}

Comment: the .get() u have above, where or what would I replace this with? Would this be under the success:? thanks for your time.

Comment: @TMan: No. Just replace the ajax function with get. get is a short form of ajax. I updated my answer.

Comment: Ok cool that worked, but I have one more question. Everytime I go to click on a link and it updates, it scrolls me up to the top of the page(screen) again as if the whole page was refreshing. Any idea how to get rid of that? thx

Comment: @TMan: Glad it worked for you. May be you remove the # from gref value and give some url there and do preventDefault/ return false at the end of your AjaxStoryClick function and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

The Ajax call is not passing the value for the parameter 'Id' to the action method
'UserStoriesList', line *'data: storyid,'* should be *'data: { id:storyid},'*

As your action method 'UserStoriesList' has a not null-able *id* parameter, server will generate a error response:

You will not see the error response if there is no callback for the
ajax error event and in debug mode the breakpoint in the action will not be hitted.

Here is updated script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function AjaxStoryClick(storyid) {

 $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("UserStoriesList", "Estimate")',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { id: storyid },
    success: function (result) {
        $('#stories').html(result);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
    }
 });
}
</script>
```

Action method:

```
public ActionResult UserStoriesList(int id)
{
  ActiveEpicId = id;
  var userstories = userRepository.Select().Where(x => x.EpicId.Equals(id)).ToList();

  if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    return PartialView("_UserStoriesList", userstories);
  else
    return View("UserStoriesList", userstories);
}
```